# Unable to save edits in Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, error

I set up a new Magento System and Migrated Data from the old Shop into the new system.

My problem now is that when i edit a product the save button is without function.

I checked the dev tools in Chrome it shows no error not even a event under network. I tried multiple other browsers. Cleared the caches.

I would greatly appreciate any Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem. It was a defective Attribute we migrated from 1.9

If you have the same problem try to create/edit a product with the default Attribute set. If it works compare your set to the default.